# Azure DevOps NPM task returns 403 while bash task succeeds

Tags: bash, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to switch from using Azure DevOps Bash task to NPM task and when running the NPM task it fails with 403 while with Bash task it works.
This is the bash task that is working:

```
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'npm ci'
        target:
          commands: any
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: 'npm ci'
          workingDirectory: './apps/${{ parameters.appName }}'
```

and this is the npm task that I'm getting an error for:

```
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm ci'
        target:
          commands: any    
        inputs:
          command: 'ci'
          workingDir: './apps/${{ parameters.appName }}'
```

This is the complete error I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/AzDevOps_azpcontainer/.npm/_logs/2022-11-20T14_20_22_151Z-debug-0.log
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: npm ci
```

In general I wanted to know what's the difference between these two tasks? Aren't they supposed to be identical? And what could be causing the different result?

Comment: Looking at NPM@1 task source  and BashV3 task source : https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NpmV1/package.json. It seems like that both contain node that support npm command  .So i think it is rather a mater of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [Azure DevOps Service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for [npm repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#npm-service-connection) and specifically with the credentials you use for *npmjs*.

The NPM task for Azure DevOps can use the Service Connection as specified in the [docs for the NPM task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops#arguments)

Comment: How is it working with a Bash task then? Shouldn't it need that same Service connection?

Comment: ++ And regarding the fields I need to fill when creating the Service connection - how can I know what is the username & password I'm using for example when I run it with Bash?

Comment: Nmp task and bash task are two kinds of task provided by devops. Bash task doesn't need a service connection and it's similar to run npm command in command line tool in your local machine. and it downloads packages directly from npmjs. Check `Registry to use` in your npm task.